# How can I integrate the RecyclerView with images in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create the image gallery . I am using the recyclerview for the same as there can be large number of images. This is what I am trying to do :

1. When the user opens up the app android will ask for its permission for images (working)
2. After selecting either option add it to the image view present in the recyclerview (not working).
3. If image is saved how to re-render it back to the recyclerview (not working)

Here is what I am trying to do :
This is my Activity file named *GalleryActivity.java*  :

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.traveloholic.R;
import com.traveloholic.models.Gallery;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.imagegallery);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        Gallery galleryObj = this.getImage();
        GalleryAdapter adapter = new GalleryAdapter(GalleryActivity.this, galleryObj);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    
    private Gallery getImage(){
        Gallery galleryObj = new Gallery();
        galleryObj.setImageUrl("");
        galleryObj.setImageTitle(null);
        return galleryObj;
    }
    
    public void getImage(ImageView img){
        this.imageView = img;
        this.selectImage(GalleryActivity.this);
    }

    private void selectImage(Context context) {
        final CharSequence[] options = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery", "Cancel"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Choose your profile picture");

        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    Intent takePicture = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);

                } else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, 1);//one can be replaced with any action code

                } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 0:
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                        Bitmap selectedImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                        this.imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                    }

                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                        if (selectedImage != null) {
                            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                            if (cursor != null) {
                                cursor.moveToFirst();

                                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                                this.imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                                cursor.close();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is the layout file *activity_galler.xml* :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.GalleryActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gallery_screen_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/gallery_screen_message"
        android:textSize="@dimen/page_identifier_textSize"
        android:fontFamily="@font/sanfranciscodisplay_bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/page_identifier_marginTop"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gallery_screen_submessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/gallery_screen_message"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:fontFamily="@font/sanfranciscodisplay_regular"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/imagegallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/gallery_screen_submessage"
        android:layout_marginBottom="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_signup_first_marginTop">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/continue_to_fourth"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_layout_first"
        android:fontFamily="@font/sanfranciscodisplay_regular"
        android:text="@string/continue_msg"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_signup_marginBottom"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">
    </Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Adapter class *GalleryAdapter* :

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.traveloholic.R;
import com.traveloholic.models.Gallery;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    
    private Gallery galleryObj;
    private Context context;


    public GalleryAdapter(Context context, Gallery galleryObj) {
        this.galleryObj = galleryObj;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_cell_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(galleryObj.getImageUrl()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //return galleryList.size();
        return 1;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        //private TextView title;
        private ImageView img;
        private ImageButton addRemoveButton;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
            addRemoveButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_remove_icon);

            this.addOperationToAddButton();
        }

        private void addOperationToAddButton(){
            addRemoveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View view) {
                       GalleryActivity galleryActivity = (GalleryActivity)context;
                       galleryActivity.getImage(img);
                   }
               }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my another layout file *image_cell_layout.xml* :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_layout_five"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/image_layout">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/photo_placeholder" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/add_remove_icon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/add_image" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone help me with this how can I solve the three problems mentioned above . Any better aproach to do all this ??

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered the [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library?

Comment: Yes , I tried Glide and Picasso both , but nothing worked out.